# section navigation doesn´t work with firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll, sticky

I´m trying to create a page with a title-img for each section. Each title (for each section) has position: sticky, so when scrolling down (or navigate via the side navigation) each picture gradually rolls over the current viewport until sticking to top: Opx;

```
<nav id="sidenav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-title" title="">LIAV</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-one" title="">cabinets</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-three" title="">bed</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
<main class="main-content">
            <section class="section"   id="section-title">
                <img class="image" id="home-img" src="images\home.jpg" alt="home">
            </section>

            <section class="section"   id="section-one">
                <img class="image" id="cabinet-img" src="images\wood web pic\cabinet-two.jpg">
            </section>

            <section class="section"   id="section-three">
                <img class="image" id="section-three-img" src="images\home.jpg" alt="home">
            </section>


        </main>
```

So far so good, here the relevant bits in the **`CSS`**:

```
.main-content{
    position: relative;             /*Sticky Container*/
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding-top: ;
    height:;
    width: 80vw;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: ;
    padding-top: ;
    margin-bottom: ;
}

#section-title{
    position: sticky;
    top: 1px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 83.9%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: ;
    margin-bottom:  0;
}


#home-img{
    position:;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100% ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#section-one{
    position: sticky;
    top: 1px;
    width: 93.9%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}

#cabinet-img{
    position:;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100% ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#section-three{
    position: sticky;
    top: 1px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 83.9%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: ;
    margin-bottom:  0;
}

#section-three-img{
    position:;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100% ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

All this works as intended on manual scrolling. The images stick nicely, roll up and down, I´m happy. Also clicking the relevant section in the navigation smooth-scrolls me where I want- until I use Firefox. Starting from top of the page going down the links/ section-anchor works perfectly.
But when I want to navigate back to the title or a section above, it does nothing (scrolling back manually to the top - no problem). I tested Chrome and Opera, no issues at all.
This seems to be related with the position:sticky of the section, as for it works "normal" with not positioning the sections.

Does anybody have experience with that? Is this fixable without `JS` (although I know time will come when I have to make friends with it...)?

Thanks in advance,

Uli